# Redshift - Insert data into a temp table with a condition : column doc_id should be unique and not null

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a temp table and insert data into it in Redshift.
My goal is to create a single record for **unique** doc_id WHERE doc_id **IS NOT NULL**.

Here's my code:

```
-- Creating temp table to load only rows with unique and not null doc_id
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TMP_table CASCADE;

CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TMP_table
(
    uuid varchar,
    id integer,
    doc_id integer,
    revenue double,
    doc_date varchar,
);

-- insert into the temp table and add the distinct and not null filter on the doc_id
INSERT INTO TMP_table
(
    uuid,
    id,
    doc_id,
    revenue,
    doc_date
)
SELECT
    uuid,
    id,
    select DISTINCT (table_x.doc_id) from schema.table_x where table_x.doc_id IS NOT NULL,
    revenue,
    doc_date
FROM schema.table_x;
```

Upon running the above code I get a syntax error near the select subquery in the insert statement. And I can't seem to figure out what the error is.

Any guidance please?

Comment: Postgres <> Redshift.  I removed the tag.  Your code is syntactically incorrect (in any database).  It is not clear what you are trying to do.  A clear explanation, sample data, and desired results are your friends.

Comment: WHERE clause goes after the FROM clause

Comment: This line does not make sense: `select DISTINCT (table_x.doc_id) where table_x.doc_id IS NOT NULL,`. There is no `FROM`. If you are wanting to use data from `schema.table_x` in the outer SELECT, then it should not be using an inner SELECT. I agree with @Gordon -- it isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BillWeiner John Rotenstein thanks for your answers. The missing FROM clause is my bad as I was changing the table name and columns from the original script to the post. It's within the inline subquery originally, but I still get that error near DISTINCT. My goal is to create a single record for unique doc_id
WHERE doc_id IS NOT NULL. I hope this is more clear

Comment: @JohnRotenstein ^

Comment: If you run that `SELECT DISTINCT` line on its own, does it work? How many rows does it return (hopefully just one)? Then, if you just run the `SELECT uuid ... SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM schema.table_x`, does it work?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No the DISTINCT doesn't return 1 line it returns 5, I just want to be able to insert rows with unique and not null doc_id, thus my subquery on doc_id which runs fine by itself but I don't know why it fails as a subquery, so I'm asking for more guidance. I hope that clarifies things

Comment: @JohnRotenstein To be specific, the error I get is: Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "select" Position 348 (which is the select in the subquery)

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to create a single record for unique doc_id WHERE doc_id IS NOT NULL.

In Redshift, use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT uuid, id, doc_id, revenue, doc_date
FROM (SELECT x.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_id) as seqnum
      FROM schema.table_x x
     ) x
WHERE doc_id IS NOT NULL AND seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I get : Invalid operation: Operation not supported on external tables.

Comment: @GeoSal . . . I am not aware of such a limitation on external tables.